# are integration limit to find expected value from a pdf inclusive (or exclusive)?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, statistical-mechanics

This is my probability density function (pdf)
$$pdf = e^{-\frac{r}{\lambda}} \frac{1}{\lambda}$$

I want to find the expected value (EV) from $0<r \leq r_0$, $r$ is the random variable.

My first attempt is $EV_1 - EV_2$ (see below calculation), but this does not work.

The solution from the paper is $EV_3 + EV_4 = \lambda - \lambda e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda}}$

my questions:

1. Are integration limits used to find expected value from a pdf inclusive (or exclusive)? it seems like the lower limit is inclusive but the upper limit is exclusive. Any reference that I can look about this?
2. What is the interpretation of $EV_4$?

Here are some values that I calculated.
$$EV_1 = \int_0^\infty r \left(e^{-\frac{r}{\lambda}} \frac{1}{\lambda} \right) dr  = \lambda $$

$$EV_2 = \int_{r_0}^\infty r \left(e^{-\frac{r}{\lambda}} \frac{1}{\lambda} \right) dr  = r_0 e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda}} + \lambda e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda}} $$

$$EV_3 = \int_{0}^{r_0} r \left(e^{-\frac{r}{\lambda}} \frac{1}{\lambda} \right) dr  = \lambda - r_0 e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda}} - \lambda e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda}} $$

$$EV_4 = \int_{r_0}^\infty r_0 \left(e^{-\frac{r}{\lambda}} \frac{1}{\lambda} \right) dr  = r_0 e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda}} $$

This question is actually a physical formulation that I am reading. SO, if you need more explanation about the problem, let me know.

EDIT:
These are the 3 references I used. They are discussing the same thing in the screenshots I attached.

1. https://doi.org/10.1080/00018735200101151
   [image: https://doi.org/10.1080/00018735200101151]
2. https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1950.0077
   [image: https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1950.0077]
3. https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1950.0107
   [image: https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1950.0107]

Comment: Your pdf doesn't integrate to 1 over 0 to $r_0$.  You need to fix that first.

Comment: why should my pdf integrate to 1 over 0 to $r_0$?
it does integrate to 1 over 0 to $\infty$.

Comment: "I want to find the expected value (EV) from 0<r≤r0, r is the random variable."

Comment: I do not want to find the EV of the whole possible r.v., but limited to $0<r\leq r_0$. Maybe the word mean or average is more proper?

Comment: You seem to be using very non-standard terminology.  (Is this terminology from some electrical engineering statistics course?)  An expected value requires a pdf to integrate to 1 (or sum to 1 if discrete).  Otherwise you're just finding disjoint parts of an integral (that is an expected value).  Finding the expected value of $r$ given that $0< r\leq_0$ is labeled $E(r|0<r\leq r_0)$.

Comment: Referencing "the paper" might help.

Comment: If you can access one of the reference, I will delete the screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the references you give, it is now clear that you want the mean of a censored distribution rather than a truncated distribution.  Specifically, if you have a random variable $r$ with pdf $\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{r}{\lambda }\right)}{\lambda }$, then you want the mean of the censored variable $s$ which is $s=r$ if $0<s\leq r_0$ and $s=r_0$ if $r>r_0$.

$$E(s)=\int_0^{r_0} \frac{r \exp \left(-\frac{r}{\lambda }\right)}{\lambda } \, dr + \int_{r_0}^{\infty } \frac{r_0 \exp \left(-\frac{r}{\lambda }\right)}{\lambda } \, dr$$

$$=\left(\lambda -e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda }} (\lambda +r_0)\right)+\left(r_0 e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda }}\right)=\lambda -\lambda  e^{-\frac{r_0}{\lambda }}$$

Comment: TIL new things. thanks.

Comment: Me, too.  I've never hear of TIL before (until now and googling it).  I should have assumed a large age difference.  (I'm retired.)  And if you really need an interpretation of the two parts that might be the following:  (1) the conditional mean $E(r|0<r\leq r_0)$ times the probability of $0<r\leq r_0$ and (2) $r_0$ times the probability that $r>r_0$.